# Trying to use ObjC with JXA: TypeError on simplest example

Tags: javascript, objective-c, javascript-automation

I'm trying to use ObjC with JXA. Here is a simplest possible example:

```
ObjC.import('Foundation')
str = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String('foo')
console.log(str)
```

This code gives me an `Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.NSString.alloc')`.

The same happens if I remove the 'import' line (as far as I understand symbols from the Foundation framework are available by default in JavaScript for Automation).

Why this happens?

**Update:** I'm using Big Sur (beta 2). Looks like something is broken in JXA<->ObjC bridge.

Thanks!

Comment: just guessing: maybe its str = $.(NSString.alloc()).initWithUTF8String('foo')
even thinking you don't need the $

Comment: What version of macOS are you using and what editor are you using ?  On _Script Editor_ in Catalina, you code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Ah, quite possible this is the issue: I'm testing Big Sur (bate 2). Looks like something is broken inside JXA<->ObjC bridge (I'm using Script Editor). Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ValeryKondakoff did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing the same issue on the Big Sur 11.2.1